# Tengo un problema con mi calculadora

Tags: php, html

Tengo el siguiente problema: La variable $re no me funciona como yo busco que lo haga. Intento que la variable $re obtenga los valores correspondientes a la operación que el usuario establezca, ya sea por suma, resta... etc.

Los errores que me saltaron fueron que la variable no está definida o no tiene valor, no se como hacer para que php reconozca la variable y su contenido correspondiente.

Código php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["n1"]) && isset($_POST["n2"])) {
    if ($_POST["op"] == "+") {
        return $re = $_POST["n1"] + $_POST["n2"];
    }else
    if ($_POST["op"] == "-") {
        return $re = $_POST["n1"] - $_POST["n2"];
    }else
    if ($_POST["op"] == "*") {
        return $re = $_POST["n1"] * $_POST["n2"];
    }else
    if ($_POST["op"] == "/") {
        return $re = $_POST["n1"] / $_POST["n2"];
    }
}


require "views/index.view.php";
```

---

y el código html no lo puedo copiar acá porque en vez de mostrarlo, lo ejecuta.
 [image: Esta es la captura de mis códigos PHP y HTML:]

Comment: agrega el código como texto, así como imagen no se distingue nada

Comment: Conste que intente crear un input tipo hidde, (que quedó suelto ahí) para así poder utilizar la variable $_POST["re"] pero me salía el mensaje de que la variable no servía por alguna razón.

Comment: Deberías leer el [tour] de bienvenida para ver cómo hacer una buena pregunta. El código se lee mejor como texto. Además ese texto se puede copiar y pegar para hacer pruebas en nuestros entornos o para añadirlo en la respuesta, corregido o comentado

Comment: Posiblemente [Te han votado negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/)

Comment: ya he editado mi pregunta para que sea más clara.

Comment: **Todo** el código debe ir directamente en la pregunta, inclúyelo y nosotros te ayudamos a darle formato

Comment: Gracias a todos, logré solucionar mi problema y como la mayoria de los demás, era una cosa chiquita que no vi antes.

Answer (score 1):

Mira esto y ejecutalo en tu local
`

## Calculadora

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="n1" value="">
        <select name="op" size="1">
            <option value="+">+</option>
            <option value="-">-</option>
            <option value="*">*</option>
            <option value="/">/</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="n2" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="re">
    </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
        <?php 
            if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                if (isset($_POST["n1"]) && isset($_POST["n2"])) {
                    echo "<br>Resultado: ";
                    if (isset($_POST["op"])=="+") {
                        echo $_POST["n1"]+$_POST["n2"];
                    }
                    if (isset($_POST["op"])=="-") {
                        echo $_POST["n1"]-$_POST["n2"];
                    }
                    if (isset($_POST["op"])=="*") {
                        echo $_POST["n1"]*$_POST["n2"];
                    }
                    if (isset($_POST["op"])=="/") {
                        echo $_POST["n1"]/$_POST["n2"];
                    }
                }
            }

         ?>

</form>
```

`

Comment: y eso como por qué?

Comment: Porque cuando haces click en el boton submit se ejecuta lo que esta dentro de esta condicion `if(isset($_POST["submit"]))` y dentro de esa condicion solo estas imprimiendo la variable `$re` que no la estas inicializando en ningun lado.

Comment: Lo intente, y como muchos otros intentos más, al apretar suprimir, la página se vuelve en blanco y poniendo "ver fuente del codigo" solo aparece una fila vacía.

Comment: Mira este codigo, esto es lo basico que quieres hacer, de ahi en adelante queda de tu parte:

`<input type="submit" name="submit">
 <?php 
  if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
   if (isset($_POST["n1"]) && isset($_POST["n2"])) {
   echo "<br>Resultado: ";
   if (isset($_POST["op"])=="+") {
   echo $_POST["n1"]+$_POST["n2"];
   }
   if (isset($_POST["op"])=="-") {
   echo $_POST["n1"]-$_POST["n2"];
   }
   if (isset($_POST["op"])=="*") {
   echo $_POST["n1"]*$_POST["n2"];
   }
   if (isset($_POST["op"])=="/") {
   echo $_POST["n1"]/$_POST["n2"];
   }
  }
 }`

Comment: Sigue dando el mismo error, página en blanco. Tal vez simplemente me de por vencido y lo intente en un futuro.

Comment: Mira la edicion de la respuesta. Crea un html desde cero y copia y pega lo que hay en el form incluyendolo